# Focussing a input inside a grid with overflow hidden, triggers full layout in Safari

Tags: safari, grid

**OBS! This bug only happens in Safari.**

1. Have a grid layout with a fixed `height` and `overflow: hidden`.
2. Add a child element with `overflow-y: auto`.
3. Makes sure the content inside the child is too big to fit and place an input field at the end.

Now then you scroll to the bottom and click/focus the input field, Safari will trigger a full layout change and scroll the child to top.

Heres a simple codepen example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OorVGv

Comment: Have the same issue.
Safari version 12.1 (13607.1.40.1.5).
Try to set a height to a child, it can help on some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a height to a child, it can help on some cases.